# How to show letters from A until user input in small or caps?

Tags: javascript

I have manage to show small letters

```js
var first = "A",
  last = window.prompt(" enter your char");
for (var i = first.charCodeAt(0); i <= last.charCodeAt(0); i++) {
  console.log(eval("String.fromCharCode(" + i + ")") + " ")
}
```

Comment: Your description is not matching the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `eval` here

```js
let last = prompt('enter your char'),
  first = last.toLowerCase() === last ? 'a' : 'A';

for (let i = first.charCodeAt(0); i <= last.charCodeAt(0); i++)
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(i));
```

Comment: i want to print the letters till user input, but in this code only small letter or caps letter is getting printed. if the user inputs anything small it will not work. how to do that weather its capital or small its going to get printed

Comment: If the user enters 'z', it will print all characters from ASCII code 65 to 122, which includes both caps A-Z and small a-z. Updated the snippet to add the lower/upper condition on first letter

Comment: can u make me understand the code a bit. m new to javascript specially this part 
 first = last.toLowerCase() === last ? 'a' : 'A';

Comment: The expression uses a ternary operator here, if the entered char/string is lowercase, first will be set 'a' otherwise 'A'. Read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: IF I HAVE TO USE QUEUE TO DO THAT HOW WILL I DO IT ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the input character is an uppercase character or not. If it is an uppercase character then the first character is `'A'` else it is `'a'`.

````
first = (last.toUpperCase() == last) ? 'A' : 'a';
for (var i = first.charCodeAt(0); i <= last.charCodeAt(0); i++) {
  console.log(eval("String.fromCharCode(" + i + ")") + " ")
}```
````